# Value of type 'Any' has no member 'text in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

```
@IBAction func endEditingText(_ sender: Any) {

    let baseURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q"
    let APIKeysString = "&appid=14b92e1046c4b6e4f4d5adda8259131b"
    guard let cityString = sender.text else {return}
    if let finalURL = URL (string:baseURL + cityString + APIKeysString) {
        requestWeatherDate(url: finalURL)

    } else {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type cast sender to UITextField.

```
@IBAction func endEditingText(_ sender: Any) {
    let textFieldObject = sender as! UITextField
    ....
}
```

or at the time of creating IBAction you can use UITextField in place of Any.

```
@IBAction func endEditingText(_ sender: UITextField) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: when v want to use particular thing like uitextfiled or any other method v need to cast ??

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear. The `sender` is declared as `Any` so the compiler does not know the actual static type.

Change it to `UITextField`:

```
@IBAction func endEditingText(_ sender: UITextField) { ...
```